# Почему крашится приложение при открытии?

Tags: java, android

При попытке открыть приложение оно крашится!

Код ошибки

```
Process: com.buratinoapps.toplistbitcoin, PID: 9638
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.buratinoapps.toplistbitcoin.MainActivity$1.getItemViewType(MainActivity.java:71)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6186)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:757)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20699)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6198)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2870)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2397)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1532)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7419)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:888)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:819)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

MainActivity.class код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemViewHolder> adapter;

    SparseBooleanArray expandState = new SparseBooleanArray();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lst_item);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        retrieveData();

        setData();
        
    }

    private void setData() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Items");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Item> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
                .setQuery(query, Item.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                if(items.get(position).isExpandable())
                    return 1;

                else
                    return 0;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Item model) {

                switch (holder.getItemViewType()){

                    case 0:
                    {
                        ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder)holder;
                        viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                        viewHolder.txt_item_text.setText(model.getText());

                        viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+items.get(position).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    break;

                    case 1:
                    {
                        final ItemViewHolder viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder)holder;
                        viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                        viewHolder.txt_item_text.setText(model.getText());

                        viewHolder.expandableLinearLayout.setInRecyclerView(true);
                        viewHolder.expandableLinearLayout.setExpanded(expandState.get(position));
                        viewHolder.expandableLinearLayout.setListener(new ExpandableLayoutListenerAdapter() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPreOpen() {
                                changeRotate(viewHolder.button,0f,180f).start();
                                expandState.put(position,true);
                                
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onPreClose() {
                                changeRotate(viewHolder.button,180f,0f).start();
                                expandState.put(position,false);
                            }
                        });

                        viewHolder.button.setRotation(expandState.get(position)?180f:0f);
                        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                viewHolder.expandableLinearLayout.toggle();
                            }
                        });

                        viewHolder.txt_child_item_text.setText(model.getText());
                        viewHolder.txt_child_item_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+viewHolder.txt_child_item_text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+model.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

                if(viewType == 0){
                    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_without_child, viewGroup, false);
                    return new ItemViewHolder(itemView, viewType == 1);
                }
                else{
                    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_with_child, viewGroup, false);
                    return new ItemViewHolder(itemView, viewType == 1);
                }
            }
        };

        expandState.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
            expandState.append(i,false);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ObjectAnimator changeRotate(RelativeLayout button, float from, float to) {
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "rotation", from, to);
        animator.setDuration(300);
        animator.setInterpolator(Utils.createInterpolator(Utils.LINEAR_INTERPOLATOR));
        return animator;
    }

    private void retrieveData() {
        items.clear();

        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("items");
        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot itemSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Item item = itemSnapShot.getValue(Item.class);
                    items.add(item);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("ERROR", ""+ databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.startListening();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.stopListening();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Ошибку показывает на 71 строке

```
if(items.get(position).isExpandable())
```

Comment: "крошиться"? - Because that's the way the cookie crumbles.

Comment: items.get(position) - вы пытаетесь получить элемент по индексу из коллекции, при этом ваш индекс больше размера коллекции. вы выходите за пределы коллекции и получает исключение. поставьте логер перед этим вызвовом и посмотрите, сколько элементов в вашей коллекции и какой индекс прилетает. либо прйдитесь дебагером

Comment: Потому что IndexOutOfBoundsException. Написано в самом начале сообщения об ошибке.